# Get Firebase Doc ID

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm trying to work with Firebase. For comfortable work I use "react-firebase-hooks".

How do I get the **doc id** and **doc data** at the same time to transfer them to props? So far I can only get the **doc data**.

```
const TodoList: FC = () => {
    const [user] = useAuthState(auth)
    const [todos] = useCollectionData(collection(db, `users/${user?.email}/todos`))

    return (
        <section className="todo-list">
            {todos?.map(todo => (
                <Todo isCompleted={todo.isCompleted} text={todo.text} />
            ))}
        </section>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve this using custom converter

```
const yourConverter = {
    toFirestore(post) {
        return { ... }
    },
    fromFirestore(snapshot, options) {
        const data = snapshot.data(options)
        return {
            id: snapshot.id,
            data: data.text,
        }
    },
}
const reference = firestore
.collection(`users/${user?.email}/todos`)
.withConverter(converter);
```

Related helpful [documentation can be found here](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#transforming-data)